# How to add values through interpolation for multiple observations (samples) in R?

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a data set in R: observations are in rows, and variables are columns. Each observation is a sample that has percentage data in certain bins (the variables), which add up to 100%.  Observations and variables have headings (rows have sample name, columns have a number range for each bin). Example is below with headings:

```
$ Channel_diameter_um       : num  0.375 0.412 0.452 0.496 0.545 ...
 $ X2                        : num  0.0366 0.0648 0.0957 0.1379 0.1757 ...
 $ X3                        : num  0.0424 0.0751 0.1115 0.1625 0.2106 ...
 $ X8                        : num  0.0159 0.0281 0.0415 0.0602 0.0772 ...
 $ X9                        : num  0.0294 0.052 0.0771 0.1118 0.1439 ...
 $ X17                       : num  0.0157 0.0278 0.041 0.059 0.0749 ...
 $ X22                       : num  0.0403 0.0712 0.1049 0.1507 0.1912 ...
 $ X26                       : num  0.00441 0.00847 0.01446 0.0204 0.02644 ...
 $ X31                       : num  0.0333 0.059 0.087 0.1248 0.1578 ...
```

I would like to interpolate these data to fill in extra 'bins'/variables. The dataset above has 93 bins, but I would like to interpolate each observation to have 117 bins - bins which I have defined, and so that each sample still adds up to 100%.

How can I do this in R? I have looked at other interpolation problems on here but most questions seem to relate to missing data, where as I am wanting to add and modify using interpolation.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say you've defined the bins - have you defined what the bins are, or have you defined a function to do the interpolating?  (I.e., are you looking for a function that will interpolate values, or just a way to implement the function you've already defined?)

Comment: Thanks for the Q - I am looking for a function that will interpolate the values, as I have defined what the bins are.

Comment: If your bin numbers have meaningful numeric values (i.e., "X2" really does mean "2" of something), one approach to "homebrew" interpolation would be to fit some curve that predicts bin value from bin number and use that as your function.  But that might be risky if you're planning to do any kind of inferential statistics downstream.  The folks over at Cross Validated might have a better sense of whether this would be a reasonable approach, and what kind of curve to fit...

Comment: Thanks A.S.K. - I am planning on doing further stats with this data so thanks for the heads up.. I am hoping an interpolation would predict a value that fits sensibly between the bin value that comes before and after, as each bin for a sample adds up to 100%. I'll head over to Cross Validated... thanks!